# CodeDom Compiler: Which assemblies are referenced by default?

Tags: c#, vb.net, reference, runtime-compilation, system-codedom-compiler

Short: Which assemblies (Framework DLLs) are included by default in .NET CodeDom Compilers (`CSharpCodeProvider` or `VBCodeProvider`) without explicitely adding the reference to CompilerParameters?

---

I am using the `CodeDom` tools, namely `CSharpCodeProvider` and `VBCodeProvider`, to compile assemblies at runtime. I noticed, that some but not all .NET reference assemblies are included by default.

I can use everything in `System.dll` without adding the reference in the `CompilerParameters` but nothing from `System.Numerics.dll` for example. For the latter I need to add `params.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Numerics.dll")` to my code.

Hence my question: How do I know, which assemblies are referenced by default, and which are not?

**Relevant code**:

This code can be compiled without added references:

```vb
Imports System
Public Class Foo
    Public Sub TestClass
        Dim t = Tuple.Create(23,241)
    End Sub
End Class
```

This code can not:

```vb
Imports System
Imports System.Numerics
Public Class Foo
    Public Sub TestClass
        Dim t = Tuple.Create(23,241)
        Dim n As New Complex(32,112)
    End Sub
End Class
```

The code I use to compile (abbreviated):

```vb
Dim params As New CompilerParameters()
'The path of the assembly to create
params.OutputAssembly = active.OutputName

'Compile as dll
params.GenerateExecutable = False

Dim vb As New VBCodeProvider
Dim res = vb.CompileAssemblyFromSource(params, active.Code)
```

Comment: I think the answer is None.  Though it has been a while, every article I recall reading added even System to the mix.

Comment: @Plutonix That would be the expected thing. The `ReferencedAssemblies` collection of CompilerParameters is empty to begin with as well. But in the code to compile I can use namespaces like `System`, `System.IO` and so on without explicitely referencing `System.dll`.